# codeigniter menu library

Tags: codeigniter, menu

I'm searching a good menu library for codeigniter, what could be implemented fast as possible and should be simple as possible. Could somebody give me some useful tips where to search for and if there are some of out there, which one to chose?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'menu library'? A CRUD-type library for building navigation for the application?

Comment: yes that's what I'm searching for

Comment: What are the requirements then? Should it support nesting? Like sub-menu branches?

Comment: nesting would be good as well but is not a requirement

Comment: If it's not a requirement, then what's so difficult about writing a model with CRUD methods and creating a database table with three columns?

Answer (score -1):

if you want CRUD functionality to be implemented in your application, you can use GroceryCRUD.